Projective model in hyperbolic geometry
I have a confusion. Let $\mathbb H^n = \{(x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid x_1^2 +\cdots +x_{n}^2 - x_{n+1}^2 = -1\}$ be the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry. We consider the projective model of hyperbolic geometry as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb H^n &= \mathbb P(\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid x_1^2 +\cdots +x_{n}^2 - x_{n+1}^2<0 \}) \\
&= \{[x_1: \cdots: x_{n+1}] \in \mathbb{RP}^n \mid x_1^2 +\cdots +x_{n}^2 - x_{n+1}^2<0\}
\end{align*}
Here $\mathbb P: \mathbb R^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^n$ is a the canonical projection defined by $x \mapsto [x]$.
My question is: why we define $x_1^2 +\cdots +x_{n}^2 - x_{n+1}^2<0$ (less than zero) in the projective model?

Try to define it using the opposite inequality and see what you get (say, if $n=2$).

The projective model consists simply of the cone of all lines passing through the hyperboloid.

The "less than zero" is there because, for any 1-dimensional subspace $L \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$, the intersection $L \cap \mathbb H^n$ is nonempty if and only if for every nonzero point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}) \in L$ we have $x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2 - x_{n+1}^2 < 0$.

Thanks for answer.  Would it be $\mathbb H^n$ (hyperboloid model) in the answer?

Yes, thanks for the correction.
